# How can we ensure that there is a single instance of a class in a clustered environment

Tags: java, singleton, cluster-computing

How can we ensure that there is a single instance of a class in a clustered environment? The class is Serializable.

Comment: Are you using horizontal or vertical clustering ?

Comment: You mean one instance across the whole cluster, rather than one instance per node in the cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correctly implement readResolve method of your singleton class.

Preferably, I think [terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org/) would help.

This link has more help http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/771.page

Answer (score 2):

Use a container that provides application scoped singletons, e.g. Seam, Spring etc.

Comment: How will that help in a cluster?

Comment: obviously, your cluster has to run a single such container

Answer (score 0):

1. Use container which provides you with this facility.
2. If use of container is not a feasible option, then create a RemoteFactory which will provide you with instance of the class in context.